# Browser crashes without any error - reason <button> inside <form>

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications, crash, materialize

I am coding an application in Google Application Script on server side and MaterializeCSS on client side + pure javascript.

I started to experience a browser crash = `blank` screen without any error. Just some warnings

```
[Violation] 'click' handler took 1162ms
Unrecognized feature: 'ambient-light-sensor'.
Unrecognized feature: 'speaker'.
Unrecognized feature: 'vibrate'.
Unrecognized feature: 'vr'.
```

[image]

I narrowed it down to this button. The commented out code is the original one. The one with alert is just for debugging.

```
 <!-- <button id ="dotaceAdminDalsiSkola" class="waves-effect btn" onClick="dotaceAdminDalsiSkolaFun()">
      Přidat další školu</button> -->

 <button id ="dotaceAdminDalsiSkola" class="waves-effect btn" onClick="alert('testing')">
      Přidat další školu</button>
```

Right now in some cases after I click the button and then OK to alert the browser crashes down with no error but the blank screen. The button is inside a form that is inside MaterlializeCSS.

I created a video https://youtu.be/MiZehuumc4w to show that the error does not happen always. Only after the modal is populated with data. If the modal stays empty. There is no error.

```
   <!-- Dotace Modal Structure -->
  <div id="dotaceModal" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Administrace dotací</h4>
      <div class="row">
        <form id= "dotaceModalForm" class="col s12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s6">
              <input id="dotaceTitulek"  name="dotaceTitulek" type="text" class="validate" data-field-name=""  required>
              <label class="active" for="dotaceTitulek">Název dotace</label>
            </div>
 <!-- <button id ="dotaceAdminDalsiSkola" class="waves-effect btn" onClick="dotaceAdminDalsiSkolaFun()">Přidat další školu</button> -->
 <button id ="dotaceAdminDalsiSkola" class="waves-effect btn" onClick="alert('testing')">Přidat další školu</button>
          </div>
          <div id="dotaceSkolaKotva" data-counter="1"></div>
          <div id="skolaClone1" class="row dotaceSkolaClone" data-counter="1" >
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <input id="skolaName1"  name="skolaName1" class="validate dotaceSkolaNameAutocomplete" type="text"  data-counter="1" data-field-name="" autocomplete="off" onchange="session.autocomplete.currentDotaceIDCounter=this.dataset.counter">
              <label class="active" for="skolaName1">Název školy</label>
            </div>
            <input id="dotaceSkolaID1" name="skolaID1" type="text" style="display:none">
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <input id="dotaceIdentifikace" name="dotaceIdentifikace" class="validate" type="text"  data-field-name="" required>
              <label class="active" for="dotaceIdentifikace">Identifikace dotace</label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <input id="dotaceID"  name="dotaceID" type="text" style="display:none">          
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat" id="dotaceSmazat" style="float:left">Smazat</a>
      <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat" id="dotaceZrusit">Zrušit</a>
      <a href="#!" class="waves-effect waves-green btn-flat" id="dotaceUlozit" onclick="checkForm('dotaceModalForm')">Uložit</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Could someone suggest what is happening, how to debug and solve this issue?

I tested it on latest Chrome, Firefox, Vivaldi, Edge and Brave. In private mode too and without any browser extenstion. The same result for all test cases.

**UPDATE**

So the issue happens when the element `button` is inside the `form` of modal. If I place it outside it works. Could someone explain?

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: @Rubén I have no idea how to create reproducible example. I spent hours on that and I was just able to narrow it down to the point of `clicking` the button. I know exact steps how to reproduce in my environment.

Comment: Step 1. Create a new Google Apps Script project, Step 2 add doGet funciton to the default .gs file. It's opt to you how do you use the HTML Service to create the webpage but start with the minimal html/javascript/css . Start by a adding only the problematic button and deploy the web app. Step 3. Add other HTML tags and related elements until you are able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: By the way, Google Apps Script web -apps throughs some warnings all the time.

Comment: The default behavior of a "button" element inside a "form" is to *submit* that form, which is what appears to happen when the screen goes white after dismissing the alert box in your video.  You would need to prevent the default behavior.

Comment: @james you are right. This is the reason. Do you want to create an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now you have a button like this:

```
<button id="dotaceAdminDalsiSkola" class="waves-effect btn" onClick="dotaceAdminDalsiSkolaFun()">Přidat další školu</button>
```

Presumably you have some code somewhere -

```
function dotaceAdminDalsiSkolaFun() {
  // do stuff
}
```

Change the onclick call in the button slightly, to pass the click event into the function:

```
<button id="dotaceAdminDalsiSkola" class="waves-effect btn" onClick="dotaceAdminDalsiSkolaFun(event)">Přidat další školu</button>
```

And in your code, receive the event parameter, and prevent the default behavior of that event (so the form doesn't submit)

```
function dotaceAdminDalsiSkolaFun(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // do stuff
}
```